# Angular4 - post form data to rest api

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How is it possible to post form data to an external rest api?

At the moment i have an html form:

```
<form [formGroup] = "form" (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit(form.value)">
  <input name="name" formControlName="name">
  <input name="first_name" formControlName="first_name">
  <input name="last_name" formControlName="last_name">
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
 </form>
```

and then i have the function that is handling the submit in my component.ts file:

```
  onSubmit = function (user) {
    console.log(user);
    //this.http.post('http://xxx/externalapi/add', user);
  }
```

But how is it possible to post the form data to my external api? And what is the standard of sending form data with angular? Is it just a simple post request with form data as queryParams or is it standard to convert it into JSON. I can modify the api to handle whatever data is sent so thats not a problem.

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions but not including error details in regards to your actual problem. What type of error are you getting from your API? The method you've implemented of using the Angular HTTP package is what most people use. To be clear though, the second argument of the `.post()` method attaches the value to the body of the request. That means it has to be parsed from the body, and will not come from the query string. This configuration can be determined at your API level.

Comment: The method i have commented out did not send the post request. At least it seemed so because i didn't see any requests going out from chromes developer tools network tab.

Comment: And you're not seeing any errors in the console? If so, it could possibly be a CORS issue. If not, it makes it a bit harder to chase down. Did you `import` the Http package from '@angular/http' at the top of your file, and then use the DI engine to inject it into that component inside of the constructor via `private _http: Http`?

Comment: Wouldnt i see a outgoing request if it was a CORS problem? I did all the next steps you mentioned. Ill try to create a clean project so reproduce the problem and link it here.

Comment: Added an anwser. Seems i was missing .subscribe. Also puting "user" straight into post doesent add a body to the request. Had to recreate it manually.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out i have to add .subscribe() to post for it to do something.
Also if i put "user" straight into post request for some reason it sends an request with method "OPTIONS" without a body. So i have to create a queryParams string myself. If anyone can explain this or show a better way to do this i would appriciate it. Otherwise this currently works:

```
 onSubmit = function (user) {
    console.log(user);

    var body = "firstname=" + user.firstname + "&lastname=" + user.lastname + "&name=" + user.name;
    this.http.post("http://www.testtttt.com", body).subscribe((data) => {});

  }
```

Edit: another and probably even a better solution is to use JSON.stringify(user) instead of body. But subscribe() is still needed tho.

Comment: Same problem here ! A little bit angry about not founding solution for such a simple problem. http.post vs http.request ; .toPromise().then... vs .subscribe(). returning an Observable or not ?
I feel LOST !

Comment: Oups, if you're doing Angular4 versus a Spring Data Rest projet, don't forget to consider the bug https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-573. Angular doest OPTIONS before POST, so OPTIONS must be allowed from your REST server.

Comment: This worked for me. My settings: Angular 6 + Restful API which requires a form data object. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 23):

For Making as generic `Post` & `Get` Method in angular 2/4 using form data

```
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

constructor(private _http: Http) { }

get(url: string): Observable < any > {
    return this._http.get(url)
             .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json()); 
}

post(url: string, model: any): Observable <any> {
    let formData: FormData = new FormData(); 
    formData.append('id', model.id); 
    formData.append('applicationName', model.applicationName); 
    return this._http.post(url, formData)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            return response;
        }).catch(this.handleError); 
}
```

Comment: [Please post the actual code and not images of it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296)

Comment: I have formatted it. Please post the code instead of the image next time.

Comment: Thanks, @GirishBabuC. God bless you!

Answer (score 6):

How about using Typescript to make your life easier?

The html has `ngModel` two way binding.I've changed to rename the form personForm. You can add validation, but I have skipped it here.

```
 <form #personForm="ngForm"(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(personForm.value)">     
  <input name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="firstName">
  <input name="lastName" [(ngModel)]="lastName">
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
 </form>
```

On the component, you can use an interface Person which you can define in a models folder. The contents looks like this.

```
export interface Person {
  id:number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
```

And then in the submit method you can map it automatically like below.

```
onSubmit(person: Person){
  http.post('your_url', person).subscribe(status=> console.log(JSON.stringify(status)));
}
```

See how easy it is type safety? Also you can check if id is populated and either make a 'PUT' or 'DELETE' request depending on whether you want to update the person or delete.

Comment: What is doing the `subscribe(status=> console.log(JSON.stringify(status))`? Just reciving a 200ok?

Comment: @ValRob Post is normally when you create a record. So you'd problably want to get the object back. Don't mistaken status with HttpStatus there. status above is just a placeholder for what you get back. I should have renamed it to data.

Answer (score 2):

Let me contribute to the accepted answer since I don't have enough reputation to comment. Rather than pick all the form inputS one by one into a model, you could do the following

```
var model = this.forContollname.value
```

Then you could call the following

```
 var values = JSON.stringify(model)
```

The values can then be passed into your post method.
I hope this simplifies the process for someone with a large form.