# How to return data based on backend service response in angular 2

Tags: angular

I would like to write a typescript function that returns values which internally makes http.get service call. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shared any code, we cannot provide much suggestions. Probably this can help, [Angular4 - post form data to rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44554353/angular4-post-form-data-to-rest-api)