# JAVA/SPRING and ANGULAR authentication problem

Tags: angular, spring, authentication, spring-security

I am currently working on an application in JAVA SPRING and ANGULAR. I am a novice and I am trying to progress in these two languages.

I am currently finishing the entire security part but there is one last point that is blocking me. When I log in to my application, authentication fails even though the credentials are correct. I retrieve the information correctly but when sending it to the back-end it blocks.

The problem comes from a constant which apparently is not in the right format but I can't figure out how to change that.
I first tried putting it in JSON format but that obviously wasn't the right thing to do.

I share the code with you below:

In the SPRING backend:

Here is my security configuration

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.FormLoginConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.StaticHeadersWriter;

import com.tracker.EsportTracker.service.impl.AppUserDetailsService;
import com.tracker.EsportTracker.service.impl.UserService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;
    
    @Autowired
    private AppUserDetailsService appUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(appUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(
                auth-> auth
                .requestMatchers("/user/**", "/users/**","/tournaments/**","/tours/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers("").hasRole("USER")
                .requestMatchers("/login/user").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
          )
           .userDetailsService(appUserDetailsService)
           .formLogin(
                   formLogin -> formLogin
                   .loginPage("/login/user")
                   .loginProcessingUrl("/auth")
                   .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                   .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                   .permitAll()
                   )
           .logout(
                   logout -> logout
                   .logoutUrl("/signout").permitAll()
                   )
           .exceptionHandling(
                   exceptionHandling -> exceptionHandling
                   .accessDeniedPage("/accesRefuse")
                   );
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean simpleCorsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200","http://localhost:4200/"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Then the AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImp class which is implemented in the latter

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.tracker.EsportTracker.entities.User;
import com.tracker.EsportTracker.service.impl.UserService;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@Component
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImp implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler{
    
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    
    @Autowired
    HttpSession session;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        boolean admin = false;
        String username = authentication.getName();
        User personne=userService.findByUsername(username);
        session.setAttribute("User",personne);
    }

}
```

Finally the controller which manages the connection

```
import java.security.Principal;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.tracker.EsportTracker.entities.User;
import com.tracker.EsportTracker.service.interfaces.IUserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public class LoginController {
    
    @Autowired
    IUserService userService;

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value="/user")
    public ResponseEntity<User> login(Principal principal) {
        System.out.println(principal);
        if (principal != null) {
            User user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());
            return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
        }
    }
}
```

In the ANGULAR FRONT:

Here is my typed text for the login component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AppService } from '../services/app.service';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
import { User } from '../models/user';
import { SharedService } from '../services/shared.service';
import { UserComponent } from '../user/user.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {
  user = '';
  credentials = {username:'', password:''}
  constructor(private appService:AppService,private httplClient:HttpClient,private router:Router,private userService:UserService, private sharedService: SharedService) { }
  login() {
    console.log("username=" + this.credentials.username + " password=" + this.credentials.password);
  
    this.appService.authenticate(this.credentials, () => {
    });
  
    this.userService.findOneByUsername(this.credentials.username).subscribe(
      (data: User) => {
        var user: User = data;
        localStorage.setItem("UserId", user.idUser.toString());
        localStorage.setItem("Username", user.username.toString());

        this.userService.getUserTournaments(user.idUser);
        
  
        this.sharedService.changeUsername(user.username);

        this.router.navigateByUrl("/users");
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error("Une erreur s'est produite lors de la récupération des données de l'utilisateur :", error);
      }
    );
  
    return false;
  }
  

}
```

Then the service that connects to the back

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment.ts';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppService {
  authenticated = false;
  responseAll: any;
  isAdmin = false;
  str: any;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  authenticate(credentials: any, callback: any) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(credentials.username + ':' + credentials.password)
    });
    const authEndpoint = environment.apiBaseUrl + 'login/user';
    this.httpClient.get(authEndpoint, { headers:headers }).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.authenticated = true;
        this.responseAll = response;
        this.isAdmin = this.checkIfAdmin(response);
        this.str = 'Set your value here based on the response';


        if (callback) {
          callback();
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Authentication error:', error);
        this.authenticated = false;
        this.isAdmin = false;
        this.responseAll = null;
        this.str = null;
      }
    );
  }

  private checkIfAdmin(response: any): boolean {
    return false;
  }
}
```

The error that appears is:

Honestly, I looked in the Angular documentation but I don't know what to do anymore.

```
HttpErrorResponse
error
: 
null
headers
: 
HttpHeaders
lazyInit
: 
() => {…}
length
: 
0
name
: 
""
arguments
: 
(...)
caller
: 
(...)
[[FunctionLocation]]
: 
http.mjs:64
[[Prototype]]
: 
ƒ ()
[[Scopes]]
: 
Scopes[4]
lazyUpdate
: 
null
normalizedNames
: 
Map(0) {size: 0}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
message
: 
"Http failure response for http://localhost:7070/login/user: 401 OK"
name
: 
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
: 
false
status
: 
401
statusText
: 
"OK"
url
: 
"http://localhost:7070/login/user"
[[Prototype]]
: 
HttpResponseBase
```

```
2023-12-06T11:58:17.036+01:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m19728[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Securing GET /login/user
[2m2023-12-06T11:58:17.036+01:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m19728[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Securing GET /users/secu/GotaKev
[2m2023-12-06T11:58:17.042+01:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m19728[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Secured GET /login/user
[2m2023-12-06T11:58:17.050+01:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m19728[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Secured GET /users/secu/GotaKev
[2m2023-12-06T11:58:17.058+01:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m19728[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
null
je suis la méthode findByUsername de la classe serviceGotaKev
[2m2023-12-06T11:58:17.163+01:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m19728[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
[2m2023-12-06T11:58:17.173+01:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m19728[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-5][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Securing GET /users
[2m2023-12-06T11:58:17.173+01:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m19728[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-4][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Securing GET /tournaments
[2m2023-12-06T11:58:17.173+01:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m19728[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-5][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Secured GET /users
[2m2023-12-06T11:58:17.175+01:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m19728[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-4][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Secured GET /tournaments
[2m2023-12-06T11:58:17.175+01:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m19728[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-6][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Securing GET /users/secu/GotaKev
[2m2023-12-06T11:58:17.175+01:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m19728[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-6][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Secured GET /users/secu/GotaKev
je suis la méthode findByUsername de la classe serviceGotaKev
[2m2023-12-06T11:58:17.185+01:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m19728[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-6][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
[2m2023-12-06T11:58:17.187+01:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m19728[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-7][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Securing GET /users/1/tournaments
[2m2023-12-06T11:58:17.188+01:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m19728[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-7][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Secured GET /users/1/tournaments
[2m2023-12-06T11:58:17.199+01:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m19728[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-7][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
[2m2023-12-06T11:58:17.203+01:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m19728[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-5][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
[2m2023-12-06T11:58:17.209+01:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m19728[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-4][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
```

Thanking you in advance for the help

Comment: enable your spring security DEBUG logs and edit your question to include them. Some pointers, `FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));` can be removed, read the CORS chapter in the spring security official docs on the webpage, shows you exactly how to configure CORS, you also dont need ` @CrossOrigin` annotation . You use either a bean or the annotation, not both. We cant run your code, so its impossible for us without logs they will tell you the exact reason for the 401

Comment: also you are posting BASIC authentication to FormLogin, they are 2 completely separate ways of authenticating. You need to send username and password as FORM parameters in the body, and not as an Authorization header. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46333889/1840146

Comment: @Toerktumlare So on the Angular side I have to send the information to the back via a form? like a classic form?

Comment: @Toerktumlare I don't understand how to delete this line? FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));

Comment: Did you read the CORS chapter in the spring security docs on their webpage before asking me? And the code i linked, is that a form? Please…. Google FormData use the code i linked. Im not going to answer more stack overflow is not a forum.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Excuse me for still being a junior. In addition to that, I underwent a professional reconversion because this is not the job I do as a base. These things may seem simple and trivial to you, but they are not to me. Sorry to "bore" you, but I'm just looking to develop my skills.